# Can heroes have any kind of powers in One Punch Man?

Tags: one-punch-man

Something I find strange in One Punch Man is, it seems no all kinds of power seems to exist in the story. I mean, what we usually see is, people with increased strenght, resistance, regeneration, speed, (all augmentations of natural human habilities), ESP, and people who increased their power through artifacts such as cyborgs, people using special guns (like golden ball, spring mustachio, stinger, etc) and that's it. We dont see for example, heroes who can manipulate ice or fire without artifacts , invisibility, people who can naturally fire beams, wind control, water control, animal control, etc. May be I'm wrong and I don't know all the heroes, but isnt it so?

Can heroes have any kind of powers in One Punch Man?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that *a definite or correct answer to this question can only be provided by the mangaka himself/herself* as someone else might entail the need for speculation. I'll provide my views, however.

**We dont see for example, heroes who can manipulate ice or fire without artifacts , invisibility, people who can naturally fire beams, wind control, water control, animal control, etc.** Almost all of the powers you mentioned here can be done by [espers](https://onepunchman.fandom.com/wiki/Esper), except for invisibility and naturally fire beams, whatever kind of beams they may be. There's really no such thing as impossible when it comes to an author and his/her story. Anything can be made possible if the mangaka can create a situation to make things not previously included in his/her story to be possible.

However, the problem I see with ONE including, for example, invisibility and fire beams, and why I think we would not see them anytime soon, is that it is unoriginal. In *One-Punch Man*, most of the heroes apart from espers, acquired their abilities via training or some other means later in life. **They were not born with them, which sets the story apart**. Including a part where people are now born with different abilities would make it seem like *Boku no Hero Academia* or *X-Men*.

Although, again, who knows. The mangaka has control of the story so if he can make it work, then I have no complaints. So, yes, heroes can have any kind of powers in *One-Punch Man* if the mangaka wills it so.

Comment: @zibadawatimmy Which was what I stated as an exception above. As I said, 'In One-Punch Man, most of the heroes apart from espers, acquired their abilities via training or some other means later in life.'

Answer (score 0):

I dont know if it's canon or it should be considered "filler", but in th new OVA 1 of season 2 (not released at the time of the question),

> Heroes who can manipulate ice, fire and animals appeared